# Unbalanced game: probability of winning over an infinite number of possible match sequences

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory

We have 2 players, A and B, competing. The probability that A wins a match is p, making the probability that B wins a match (1-p) = q.

The game is won by player A as soon as he gets one more win than B, whereas B wins when he gets ahead x won matches.

What is the probability P(B wins) of A losing the game (i.e. B getting ahead x won matches before A gets ahead one)?

---

The difficulty for me is the unbalance in the game and the fact that there is a seemingly infinite amount of sequences that need to be considered. My experience with such games is too little to find an elegant solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this question is downvoted without comment. It seems that many questions are of this form?

Comment: Let $X_n$  be the number of wins that A is ahead then I think you can use the recursion $X_n=pX_{n-1}+(1-p)X_{n+1}$ and initial conditions... just noticed that this is the gambler's ruin recursion which is what @user137846 said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n$ (resp. $B_n$) be the number of matches won by $A$ (resp. $B$) by the $n$th match. Then,
$$
X_n = A_n - B_n
$$ 
is a random walk with transition probabilities

\begin{align}
X_{n+1} = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
                X_n + 1  & \mbox{with prob.} & p;\\ 
                X_n - 1  & \mbox{with prob.} & 1-p,
          \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
and $X_0=0$.
You are interested in the probability that $X_n$ hits $-x$ before hitting $1$, and the probability of $X_n$ hitting $1$ before $-x$. I believe this problem is equivalent to the [Gambler's ruin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin). The expressions for these probabilities and their derivation can be found in Feller's book "Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications : Volume 1".